# HTML5 EventSource data function processing previous value, not current

Tags: javascript, html, web, eventsource

I have setup a http server to send data in intervals of 20 seconds.  The data starts at 101 and this number is incremented every time.  So the sequence of numbers will be 101,102,103, etc

I also append to the data, after a ; delimiter, the timestamp that the server sends the data.

I think I have some bug in my javascript code, because I am observing this behaviour:

http server sends data "105" at 12:28:52.654

in my web page, I see data item "105" at time 12:29:12:690, ie 20 seconds later.  20 seconds is the interval that I send the data.  So it seems like the EventSource onmessage function is being called but is processing the previous data item, "104" in this case.

The web page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

let source = new EventSource('/startmonitoring');

function startCallMonitoring(){
     source.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event.data);
      addCall(event.data);
    };

     source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
        console.log("closed");
    }
    }, false);

}

function stopCallMonitoring() {
  source.close();
}

function gettime() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var hour = currentDate.getHours();
  var minute = currentDate.getMinutes();
  var second = currentDate.getSeconds();
  var millisecond = currentDate.getMilliseconds();
  return pad(hour) + ":" + pad(minute) + ":" + pad(second) + "." + millisecond;
}

function getdate() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var date = currentDate.getDate();
  var month = currentDate.getMonth(); //Be careful! January is 0 not 1
  var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
  return pad(date) + "/" + pad(month + 1) + "/" + pad(year);
}

function pad(n) {
    return n<10 ? '0'+n : n;
}

function addCall(callerid) {
  // insert new row.
  var tableref = document.getElementById('CallsTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var newrow = tableref.insertRow(0);
  var datecell = newrow.insertCell(0);
  var timecell = newrow.insertCell(1);
  var calleridcell = newrow.insertCell(2);
  var customerlinkcell = newrow.insertCell(3);
  datecell.innerHTML = getdate();
  timecell.innerHTML = gettime();
  calleridcell.innerHTML = callerid;
  customerlinkcell.innerHTML = "customerlink";
  console.log("added " + callerid + " at " + gettime());
}

</script>

</head>
<body>">

  <button onclick="startCallMonitoring()">Start Call Monitoring</button>
  <button onclick="stopCallMonitoring()">Stop Call Monitoring</button>

<table id="CallsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
             <th>Time added to table</th>
             <th>CallerID</th>
             <th>link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of event stream in Chrome developer tools.

[image: screenshot]

Why this behaviour?  How can I fix it?

Additional information regarding the server side.

I wrote the http server myself so that could be a cause.  Without sending the whole code for the server, which is quite large, here is the code using some helper functions to create an HTTP response message.

This timerfunc is called every 20 seconds.

Basically, when I see in the server console the output:

```
timerfunc() - sending: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 29
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

id: 7
data: 106;12:29:12.689
 to 192
```

Then in web browser, data item 105 is populated.

```
void http_server::timerfunc() {

    http_response rs;
    rs.status = 200;
    rs.set_version(1, 1);
    rs.add_header("Connection", "keep-alive");
    rs.add_header("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");  // this is REQUIRED
    //header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    rs.add_header("Cache-Control", "no-cache");        // not sure if required, investigate what it does
    rs.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  // think because for node.js demo was on different network - don't think need this
    //rs.add_header("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");  // doesn't work if you don't do chunking - investigate - but don't need

    static unsigned number = 100;
    std::string callerid = std::to_string(number);

    char timebuf[50] = {};
    get_timestamp(timebuf);

    rs.set_body("id: 7\ndata: " + callerid + ";" + timebuf + "\n");
    rs.set_content_length_to_body_length();

    unsigned retcode = 0;

    const size_t len = rs.get_content_length();
    for (auto client : clients) {
        std::string s = codec.make_http_response_message(rs);
        retcode = send(client, s.c_str(), s.length());

        std::cout << "timerfunc() - sending: " << s << " to " << client << std::endl;
    }
    number++;

    if (number == 999)
        number = 100;

}
```

Comment: so, at `12:29:12` you received a message from the server with data `105;12:28:52` ... and you think it's the browser that is causing this to happen? I think your server side code is probably wrong, most SSE errors are due to poor server side implementation

Comment: @JaromandaX not sure, but I see the http server console and when it sends 106, the web browser populates 105.  Also in Chrome dev tools, see 105 entry.

Comment: as I said, poor server side implementations of SSE are too common, and you haven't shown the server side at all

Comment: @JaromandaX You think it could be the way the server sends the http message.  Very likely, I wrote the http server.  I will add some server code above.

Comment: if it's PHP, most people do that very very wrong :p but yeah, add the server side code too

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be useful to publish how I eventually fixed the problem.

It was nothing to do with the client.  I had to make the following changes to the web server sending the event to make it fully work:

1. Change header in requests with event payload to Transfer-Type: chunked.
2. Payload of request must use the chunked format of \r\n\r\n0\r\n
3. For Server Sent Events the data stream to send must be prepended with "data: "

So if you wanted to send "My lovely streamed data part 1" as a stream message the http message would look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 18:40:24 GMT\r\n
Content-Type: text/event-stream\r\n
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
\r\n
24\r\n
data: My lovely streamed data part 1\r\n
0\r\n
```

Not sure if the Cache-Control header is required.

The web server can send multiple segments of text prepended with length then \r\n then string then \r\n.

Read up on Transfer-Encoding here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding